# How can I loop through all of the controls in a tab control (wpf)?

Tags: wpf, foreach, c#-4.0, tabitem

I have seen a few examples of how to do this with winforms but have been unable to get it to work in wpf as a wpf TabItem does not have a definition for Controls. Here is the code that I'm using right now, which does not work.

```
  TabItem ti = rep1Tab;
                var controls = ti.Controls;
                foreach (var control in controls)
                {
                    //do stuff
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TabItem usually contains a container control such as the default Grid. You can try looping through the children of that container control.

```
foreach (UIElement element in Grid1.Children)
        {
            //process element
        }
```

If you have to access properties of a particular control, you have to convert the element

```
 foreach (UIElement element in Grid1.Children)
        {
            //process element
            Button btn = (Button)element;
            btn.Content = "Hello World";
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the logical children, you use [LogicalTreeHelper.GetChilren()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.logicaltreehelper.getchildren.aspx).
If you want the visual children,  you use [VisualTreeHelper.GetChild()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getchild.aspx) in conjunction with [VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getchildrencount.aspx)